# FFT of resampled pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fft

I am trying to take the Fast Fourier Transform of a resampled pandas Series:

```
signal = pd.Series(thick, index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(time_list_thick,unit = 's'))
resampled_signal = signal.resample('1S').mean()
```

However if I simply try (using scipy) and just do:

```
SAMPLE_RATE = 1
DURATION = len(resampled_signal)
N = SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION

yf = fft(resampled_signal[:,1])
print(yf)
xf = fftfreq(N, 1 / SAMPLE_RATE)
```

I obtain an error `ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex` due to the
way `resampled_signal` is constructed to include the index. `resampled_signal` looks like this for reference:

```
00:00:00.419175    206.080335
00:00:01.419175    206.084340
00:00:02.419175    206.087010
00:00:03.419175    206.089681
00:00:04.419175    206.095021
.
.
.
```

Is there anyway this can be done? I wish to include the `pd.Series` form since my final aim is to resample two datasets such that they have the same number of data points, take the FFT of both signals, then subtract one from the other.

My simplified code for 1 data set is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq


datathick = "20210728_rig_thick.csv" 

with open(datathick) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        dates = [str(line.split(',')[0]) for line in lines]
        thick = [float(line.split(',')[1]) for line in lines]
        z = [float(line.split(',')[2]) for line in lines]

        date_thick = [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').time() for x in dates]

time_list_thick = []
for i in np.arange(0, len(date_thick)):
    q = date_thick[i]
    t = timedelta(hours= q.hour, minutes=q.minute,seconds=q.second, microseconds = q.microsecond).total_seconds()
    time_list_thick.append(float(t))
    

#---RESCALE-----
signal = pd.Series(thick, index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(time_list_thick,unit = 's'))
resampled_signal = signal.resample('1S').mean()
resampled_signal = resampled_signal.interpolate(method='time')

print(resampled_signal.head())

exit()
#----FFT Transform of Output and Noise ----
# Number of samples in normalized_tone

SAMPLE_RATE = 1
DURATION = len(resampled_signal)
N = SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION

yf = fft(resampled_signal[:,1])
print(yf)
xf = fftfreq(N, 1 / SAMPLE_RATE)

#------------------------------------------------
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7.,7.))

ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_zorder(1)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude (a.u)')
ax.minorticks_on() # enable minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('black')

plt.yscale('log')
ax.tick_params(direction='out', axis='y', which='both', pad=4, colors='black')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#eeeeee', linestyle='-', zorder=1, linewidth=0.4) # turn on major grid
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#eeeeee', linestyle='-', zorder=1, linewidth=0.4) # turn on minor grid

ax.plot(np.abs(xf), np.abs(yf))

plt.savefig('fft.pdf', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', format='pdf')
plt.savefig('fft.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
#----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: For debugging it would help to make up a *minimal* toy dataset that makes the error happen.  If it is `fft` that falls over when you pass in a Series, then you can maybe reproduce the error with a short hard-coded `Series` like `bad_series = pd.Series(...)`.  Also, does it help if you do something like `fft(X.values)`?

Comment: SOLVED: The issue was I forgot to interpolate the rescaled Series such that any NaNs were removed